# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'XXXX'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a Python package which looks similar to this directory structure:

```
paymod/
    client.py
    region.py
tests/
    unit.py
```

The client.py file has a class named: PayClient and has multiple methods inside it. I want to call one particular function from that class and I am importing it in Unit.py file like this:

```
from paymod.client import PayClient
```

But when I run the unit.py file by `python3 unit.py` I am constantly getting this error:

```
>> python3 unit.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "unit.py", line 2, in <module>
    from paymod.client import PayClient
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'paymod'
```

Am I missing something here? It looks fine to me but I am not able to resolve this.

Comment: You are missing the `__init__.py`. And your PYTHONPATH seems to be on `tests/`. This is why unittests should be run with a test runner that discovers the test from the project's root folder.

Comment: Could you please let me know what is a test runner in Python? FYI, I have added an __init__.py in the paymod module, but still.

Comment: It's all in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#command-line-interface). And please note that there are name conversions to follow. A test module has to start with `test`.